# Python - Synchronizing boxplot axis for comparison

Tags: python, boxplot

this is my first question on Stack so please let me know if my post isn't very clear.

How can I synchronize the range of two boxplots so that the x axis grids will be in line?

In the example below, I want the upper plot to also show grids from -10 to 10 like the lower plot, but I don't want to fix it to real numbers so that the box plots would be synchronized even if the dataset changes.

[two boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8DBr.png)

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10*mult, 8*mult), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 4]})

sns_plot = sns.boxplot(y='Overall', x='RoR', data=data_s, ax=ax0, showfliers=False)
sns_plot.set_xlabel("")
sns_plot.set_ylabel("")

sns_plot = sns.boxplot(y='AUA Bucket', x='RoR', data=data_s, order=aua_buckets, ax=ax1,showfliers=False)
sns_plot.set_xlabel("")
sns_plot.set_ylabel("")

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.98)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.98)
plt.savefig("dist_aua.png", format="png", dpi=75)
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate with the example in [the official reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot), if you align the limits of each axis, the grid will be aligned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 8), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 4]})
sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"], ax=ax0, showfliers=False)
sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"], y=tips['day'], ax=ax1, showfliers=False)
ax0.set_xlim(0,50)
ax1.set_xlim(0,50)
plt.show()
```

[image]